# Cannot delete or rename file?

Tags: internal-storage

I have a file that cannot be deleted or renamed in my internal storage. The file is 0.00 byte, and says Last modified 1/1/1970. When I tried to open it, it said the file doesn't exist. What should I do? It also couldn't be cut nor copied. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It can be kind of error done. I dont think it is creating any problem for you. Still you can do root and try deleting it from root explorer

Answer (score 0):

Even though the empty file that you have described still appears to exist in your internal storage, maybe that file has already been deleted and maybe it will not appear again the next time you restart your device.

Comment: Note that 1/1/1970 is the Epoch for *nix systems.

Comment: I restart the device plenty time, but its still there